# Dropdown bootstrap after <g:remotelink> / Ajax call in Grails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, grails

I am working on a Grails project where I have this dropdown:

```
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" >${category.getName()} <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li>
        <g:remoteLink controller="todo" action="getTodos" update="dynamic" method="GET" id="${category.id}" onSuccess="dynamics()">Ver
                    </g:remoteLink>
    </li>
            <li><a href="#">Modificar</a></li>
            <li><a>Eliminar</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

and this function on JS:

```
function dynamics(){
    $("#dynamic").addClass("dynamicSet").removeClass("dynamicBefore");
    $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();
}
```

The problem is: After the ajax call, the jscode `$(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();` the dropdown works normally but after performing another ajax call right after, the dropdown collapses and won't work unless I reload the whole page.

Anyone knows how to fix this problem
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can not grasp what are you trying to do looking at your HTML It seems to me that you have a dropdown with only one element. That element being a remoteLink. I think that is not what you are trying to do.

In any case, remoteLink and other ajax related tags are deprecated. I recommend to you to do you own implementation using jquery or other library.

Comment: Hello @Fernando, Thanks for your help, I created my own implementation of an ajax call using jQuery and I found that the function `$(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();` was supposed to be called outside of  the function  `onsuccess()` in order to re-animate the dropdown of bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Fernando recommened to implement my own ajax call instead of using `<g:remotelink>`, I changed my code to this:

```
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" >${category.getName()} <span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a data-id="${category}" onclick="dynamics('${category.id}')"  class="button">Ver
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Modificar</a></li>
    <li><a>Eliminar</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

function dynamics(id){
        $.get("<g:createLink controller='todo' action='getTodos' />",  {"id":id}, function(respuesta){
              $("#dynamic").addClass("dynamicSet").removeClass("dynamicBefore").html(respuesta)
        ;});
;}
```

The problem was that I had declared the function `$(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();` inside the function **dynamics** but after two ajax calls the boostrap drowdowns would not work, then I found the solution to this problem by declaring the mentioned function inside the `$(document).ready(function()` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#dynamic").addClass("dynamicBefore");
        $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();
    });
```